# Java Robot does not simulate TAB KEY in windows8. Why? and how can i fix it?

Tags: java, windows-8, awtrobot

I was trying to simulate TAB KEY using class `java.awt.Robot;` in **Windows8** but it does not work(just like no key pressed). I had tried in **OS X Yosemite**, it worked perfectly.

```
try {
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.setAutoDelay(50);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
}catch (AWTException e){}
```

Someone can tell me why it does not work? and how can I simulate **tab key** in **Windows8** ?

One more question, what does this method do?

```
robot.waitForIdle()
```

Comment: [waitForIdle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#waitForIdle()) it seems that it will block until all the events in the queue have been processed

Comment: @Titus thanks:), do you know why tab key does not work in windows?

Comment: Maybe you're code throws an exception (you're not printing it in the `catch` block) because you don't have the necessary permission to create a `Robot` object or maybe there is a flaw in the way that you're testing this code.

Comment: @Titus I can create Robot instance, and i tried others key like 'a' to 'z', numbers, they worked well. Oh maybe i did not show Exceptions, i will try it thanks again :)

Comment: I've just tried it on a Windows 8 system and it works.

Comment: @Titus I think i did wrong thing in code, it is working now, thankss :)

Comment: @xxxasd **what** was wrong?